# Dynamic TextSize for a TextSwitcher in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm developing simple android app which should have different texts and text size according to the clicks on it. For implementation I have used ConstraintLayout with TextSwitcher to provide animation when texts are changing. Here are sources:

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.counter.layout_main">

<TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/text_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/push_down_in"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/push_down_out" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
private TextSwitcher mTextBody;
private int mTextSize = 20;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, viewGroup, false);

    mTextBody = (TextSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.text_body);

    mTextBody.setFactory(mViewSwitcherFactory);
    mTextBody.setText(getString(R.string.intro_text));
    mTextBody.setOnClickListener(mOnSwitcherClickListener);

    return view;
}

private ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory mViewSwitcherFactory = new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        return textView;
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mOnSwitcherClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mTextSize = 40;
        mTextBody.setText(getString(R.string.text_after_click));
    }
};
```

The initial load of intro text and size are ok, but after the performing click on it only text changes not text size. So, the question is how one can change text size (larger) dynamically when it comes setFactory method of the TextSwitcher?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `TextView tv = (TextView) mTextBody .getCurrentView();` next line `tv.setTextSize(mTextSize);` please check letme know if it worked

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki, thanks indeed with your suggestion I achieved my desired result.

Comment: can you i post answer or you post answer that helps people

Answer (score 0):

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnSwitcherClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mTextSize = 40;
        mTextBody.setText(getString(R.string.text_after_click));
    }
};
```

in above method you are not changing text size you are changing only text

change with

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnSwitcherClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mTextSize = 40;
        TextView tv = (TextView)mTextBody.getCurrentView();
        tv.setText(getString(R.string.text_after_click));
        tv.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    }
};
```